# Default Ebean server is null when startup module is called [Play Framework]

Tags: playframework, ebean, playframework-2.5, akka-actor

I am using Play Framework 2.5.10 with sbt-play-ebean 3.0.0.

**My Problem**
I need to set up Akka actors for every object form one of my models on application startup. The only official way to do this is by registering a startup module. But *sometimes* the default Ebean server is not yet initialised when the startup module is called.

**My ugly solution**

Startup Module:

```
public class StartupModule extends AbstractModule implements AkkaGuiceSupport {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bindActor(MainActor.class, "main-actor");
  }
}
```

Constructor of MainActor class:

```
@Inject
public MainActor(ActorSystem system) {
  this.system = system;

  boolean ebeanReady = false;
  EbeanServer ebeanServer = null;

  do  {
    try {
      ebeanServer = Ebean.getDefaultServer();
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {
      Logger.error("Ebean not ready!");
    }

    if (ebeanServer != null) {
      ebeanReady = true;
      Logger.info("Ebean ready!");
      Ebean.runCacheWarming();
    }

  } while (!ebeanReady);

  for (Model model : Model.find.all()) {
     foo(model);
  }

}
```

Is there a better way to do this without brute-force-trying until the Ebean server has been initialised?

Comment: Maybe try to add a delay on your module on the stuff that you need to use Ebean. Have a look into the akka scheduler. I have a similar problem and I've kind solved it by doing it.

Comment: @pedroct92 I don't want to just delay the construction of MainActor.class, I'd like to be 100% sure that Ebean.default exists :-). I now have it encapsulated in a thread with 1 second sleep after each try.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I solved that by binding Ebean Dynamic Evolutions to the module:

```
public class StartupModule extends AbstractModule implements AkkaGuiceSupport 
{
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
         bind(DynamicEvolutions.class).to(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.class).asEagerSingleton();
         bindActor(MainActor.class, "main-actor");
    }
}
```